# Toggle class show div content(buttons and text field) above the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using toggle functionality .I am facing one problem that when I click the button my buttons and text field display above the text.
**EXPLAIN** 
I used toggle functionality on button click.

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/JpvAy/16/

If I used top :145px it working fine.But it not look good .
It should look like this.
If user click button contend goes down and display buttons and text field.If user click again button then it contend goes up.

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {

   $("#searchbar").toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: why coder gives negative points

Comment: Check this updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/JpvAy/17/). Is this what you want?

Comment: what you add ? why user give -3 marks it's a bad question?

Comment: Down-voting is upto each individual, I cannot explain why they do/did it. But for the other question, please refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `position` property of your `wrapper` to `relative` like shown below and it should work. (**Note:** I have changed the `top` value also).

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative; //modified this
    z-index:1;
    top:0px; //modified this
    bottom:48px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The difference between absolute and relative is that , when you have position absolute , it takes the position from the container having relative position, by default its the body of the page.Here when you give the position absolute , your elements takes the  positioning from the body , but when you have positioning relative , it takes positioning from current container #wrapper

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/JpvAy/17/)

**EDIT:** This [**link**](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) explains the difference between the various positioning values.

Comment: what is the difference in relative and absolute.?

Comment: I am checking on internet but you can explain deeply

Comment: Thanks Can you upgrade my question .Because system block me asking question..?

Comment: But you can upgrade that may be